# Как получить параметры после решетка flask python

Tags: python, flask, route

Мне на сервер (flask python) приходит запрос по ссылке типо

> https://mysite.org/#info_a=9&info_b=595&info_c=3344343

Вопрос: как мне получить парамерты info_a, info_b и info_c?

P.S. 
Пытался добыть из request.url, но он возращает только https://mysite.org/

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.query_string

Comment: Никак. Браузеры не отправляют #fragment part

Answer (score 0):

Да, через flask и вправду невозможно, но можно в ответе отправить такой js:

```
location.href=location.href.replace('#','?')
```